# Why does result after subList and addAll will be so weird?

Tags: java

```
    List<Integer> rest = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    rest.add(1);
    rest.add(2);
    rest.add(3);

    rest.subList(0, 1);
    rest.subList(1, 3);

    println(rest);

    int i = 1;
    List<Integer> newRest = rest.subList(0, i);
    newRest.addAll(rest.subList(i + 1, rest.size()));

    println(rest);
```

`println` is method to print list, why the first `println` will print [1,2,3], but second `println` will print [1,3,2,3]

Comment: Did you debug it to see what's happening?

Comment: What do you expect a call to `rest.subList` to do, when you ignore the return value (the first two calls)? And what are you *really* trying to achieve? This seems like an odd way of doing it.

Comment: @JonSkeet this is just some test code to demo the problem.

Comment: @Cooper.Wu: But do you understand that `rest.subList(0, 1);` as a statement is pointless? If so, why have you included it in your demo code? The fact that you'd have it at all *suggests* that you thought calling the method would change the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the explanation in the javadoc for [`subList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)):

> *...The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa...*

In other words, adding an element to a sublist adds it to the original list too.

Comment: thanks, i red it before posted the question, but didn't understand it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the official Java documentation:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

In your code, newRest holds a reference to rest, so when you add items to newRest you're also adding them to the original list. The proper way of doing this is initializing newRest with a new ArrayList() like this:

> ```
>   List<Integer> newRest = new ArrayList<Integer>();
>     newRest.addAll(rest.subList(0, i));
>     newRest.addAll(rest.subList(i + 1, rest.size()));
> ```

Hope this helps you.